# Sencha EXT json not loaded if not correct to model

Tags: json, extjs, model, store

I have a Store which is connected to a model. I dynamically load different JSON structures to this store. Somethimes the JSON structures are different from the model. All the different values don't get loaded.

Example:

```
**Model:**

name
id
description


**JSON:**
[{"name":"John",
"id":"2",
"description": "Doe",
"age": "23"}]
```

In this case age woun't get loaded into the store because it is not specified in the model. How can I achieve loading this values into the store without changing the model. Is this even possible?

Another thing: What about relationships? In Sencha Architect you can specify realations between models. The properties which belong to a relationship also woun't get loaded.

Example:

```
**Model:**

id 
name
relationship: hasManyPets

**JSON:**

[{"id":"1",
"name":"John",
"pets":[{//somePet},{//somePet}]]
```

In this case pets woun't get loaded even if they are present in the model and specifed under a relationship.

I have tried adding association keys matching the name of the JSON attribute and also changing the association name to the JSon attribute but I did not help

Answer (score 0):

For the problem 1, I guess below logic could help:

once you created your store[e.g. someStore] and model [e.g. someModel], add below steps::

```
    var fields = [];
    someStore.each(function(item) {
        fields.push(Ext.create('Ext.data.Field', {
            name: item.get('field')
        }));
    });
fields.push(Ext.create('Ext.data.Field', {
            name: 'age'
        })); // add age field
    someModel.prototype.fields.removeAll();
    someModel.prototype.fields.addAll(fields);
```

When load is called on a store, age field will be loaded correctly.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Whit this code you dynamically add the a field to a store. What about the JSON?